# How to compare current week's data to last year's same time period

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

If I am looking at data for the first 10 days of a month, how can I also look at data for the first 10 days of the previous month?

I essentially want to see exactly what was happening the month prior (but for however long in the current month I am at the moment).

Example:

It is 10/11 and I am seeing Octobers data. I would see everything from 10/1 to 10/11.

I then also want to see what the data looked like from 9/1 to 9/11

Would I use the Interval and/or "date_trunc" functions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use date_trunc to get to the start of the month and you can subtract an interval of 1 month to get last month:

```
postgres=# select now(), date_trunc('month', now()) as start_of_month, now() - interval '1 month' as last_month, date_trunc('month', now() - interval '1 month') as start_of_last_month;
              now              |     start_of_month     |          last_month           |  start_of_last_month
-------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------
 2019-10-11 18:57:22.385666+00 | 2019-10-01 00:00:00+00 | 2019-09-11 18:57:22.385666+00 | 2019-09-01 00:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

Comment: But this doesn't give me all the data for 10/1 through 10/11 and then all the data from 9/1 through 9/11, does it?

Comment: This is how you would calculate the dates.  You could join on these calculated dates, but without knowing anything about your tables or data, I can't show you how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

here is how i "hacked" it:

```
select x.now, count(x.status) as total
from
(
    select now(), date_trunc('month', now()) as start_of_month, now() - 
interval '1 month' as last_month
    , date_trunc('month', now() - interval '1 month') as 
start_of_last_month, status
    , created_date
    from my_table
)x
where x.created_date between x.start_of_month and x.now
group by x.now

UNION ALL

select x.last_month, count(x.status) as total
from
(
    select now(), date_trunc('month', now()) as start_of_month, now() - 
interval '1 month' as last_month
    , date_trunc('month', now() - interval '1 month') as 
start_of_last_month, status
    , created_date
    from my_table
)x
where x.created_date between x.start_of_last_month and x.last_month
group by x.last_month
```

Using the **"UNION ALL"** I replaced **"x.now"** with **"x.last_month"** in the select and the where clause date timeframe so now i have current month (wherever in the month i'm at) and the same thing for the previous month